# Cannot assign a value to a string in a loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
import re
import os
path ="/data/notebook_files/"
Filelist = []
txt = ''
for home, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            Filelist.append(os.path.join(home, filename))
for file in Filelist:
    with open(file,"r+",encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as f:
        print (file)
        for line in f: 
            old_str = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            for i in range(0,len(old_str)):
                line = line.replace(old_str[i],"\n"+"###### v"+old_str[i],1)
            txt = line
print (txt)
```

```
import re
import os
path ="/data/notebook_files/"
Filelist = []
txt = ''
for home, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            Filelist.append(os.path.join(home, filename))
for file in Filelist:
    with open(file,"r+",encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as f:
        print (file)
        for line in f: 
            old_str = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            for i in range(0,len(old_str)):
                line = line.replace(old_str[i],"\n"+"###### v"+old_str[i],1)
            txt = line
            print(txt)
```

I'm going to add ####### before all the numbers in the text, so I just need the result of the last number, which is the result of all the numbers having been replaced. And assign it to the txt.
But the txt doesn't get printed out or written to the file.

In the first code, the txt does not print, but in the second code it prints what I want. My question is how can I continue to call the contents of the txt outside of this loop.

I would like to know how this is caused? This really bothers me.

Comment: Can you add examples of what the input files look like and what you expect the output to look like? It's a bit hard to understand what you want.

Comment: If this code doesn't print anything, then there must not be any files in `/data/notebook_files`.

Comment: True. You probably want `path ="./data/notebook_files/"` with a dot in the beginning to use relative path to where the python file is. Otherwise it's from the root of your system.

Comment: Like my data is just like 1.ababa 2.bbb 3.cccc. I wanan it change to ###### v1ababa

Comment: The directory is different in the two examples.  Which one is correct?

Comment: You can't use `replace` here.  Consider the text `"what 9 what 99 what 99"`.  Your first match would be `9`, and you would then replace ALL of the 9s.  You need to find the character indexes of the matches.  `findall` gives that to you. And remember to do the last one first, because if you change the length of the string, the rest of the indexes are wrong.

Comment: You can do this in one step.  `line = re.sub(r'\d+', r"\n###### v\1", line)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import os
import codecs
path ="/data/notebook_files/bible"
Filelist = []
for home, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if str(filename)[len(str(filename))-3:] != '.py':
                Filelist.append(os.path.join(home, filename))
for file in Filelist:
    with codecs.open(file,"r+",encoding='utf-8') as f:
        txt = ''
        for line in f: 
            #print (file)
            old_str = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            for i in range(0,len(old_str)):
                line = line.replace(old_str[i],"\n"+"###### v"+old_str[i],1).strip()
            txt += line
```

txt before opening the file inside the loop so that each time txt is assigned the empty string. Then outside the loop within the open file code, so that all the data is inside txt.

txt += line

This allows the contents of txt to be appended.